# Android 10 Camera2 API: CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE don't work

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-10.0

I have implemented the following code in my app.

```
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_NEGATIVE);
```

It has been tested on Mi9t, OnePlus 7 Pro, Huawei P20 with Android 10 and it doesn't work. While on devices with Android 9 (Redmi 5 and OnePlus 5T). It doesn't show me the negative effect on the preview.
Am i missing something?

EDIT: When a click is capture on a menu item, both capture requests are update. It works perfectly on device with Android 9.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private static final CaptureRequest.Key<Integer> EFFECT = CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE;
....


 public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.negative:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_NEGATIVE);
                return true;
            case R.id.aqua:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_AQUA);
                return true;
            case R.id.solarize:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SOLARIZE);
                return true;
            case R.id.blackboard:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_BLACKBOARD);
                return true;
            case R.id.sepia:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SEPIA);
                return true;
            case R.id.posterize:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_POSTERIZE);
                return true;
            case R.id.whiteboard:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_WHITEBOARD);
                return true;
            case R.id.effectOff:
                setCameraPreference(EFFECT,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_OFF);
        }


        return false;
    }

private void setCameraPreference(CaptureRequest.Key<Integer> key,int value){
    previewRequestBuilder.set(key,value);
    pictureRequestBuilder.set(key,value);
    updatePreview();
}
 protected void updatePreview() {
   if (null == cameraDevice) {
    }
    try {
        captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null); 
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The following method is called only when a button is pressed and after the update of the capture requests.

```
protected void takePicture() { 
    if (null == cameraDevice) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE); 

    try {
        characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId()); 
        pictureRequestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
        pictureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, CameraTools.getJpegOrientation(characteristics, rotation));
        file = CameraTools.createFilePhoto(folder); 
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageListener, null);
        captureSession.capture(pictureRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT2: i checked the available effects for my device trough:

```
int effects[] = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_EFFECTS);
    for (int effect : effects){
        Log.d("camera2d", "Effects available: "+effect);
```

The results:

```
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 0
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 1
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 2
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 3
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 4
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 5
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 8
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 7
2020-05-06 11:41:44.998 24702-24702/it.runningexamples.recamera2 D/camera2d: Effects available: 6
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle?

Comment: Do those devices list that effect in their list of supported effects (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AVAILABLE_EFFECTS) ?  Are you building the capture request after changing this setting, and using it consistently for both preview and still capture? Posting more of your code would make it easier to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: @EddyTalvala The post has been update. I think that something in android 10 changed. 
I'll try to see if newer devices have fewer options for effects ASAP. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Someone can help?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. On some devices the effects were not displayed while taking the picture, but then they are applied on the taken photo anyway